# How to get rid of spaces when using charCodeAt and charCodeFrom?

Tags: javascript

This function includes a  ROT13 cipher, which first splits the provided string and shifts the values by 13. The only problem is that it includes dashes between the words when returned, and I'm not sure how to solve that problem.

```
function rot13(str) { 

var strSplit = str.split('');
var strMap = strSplit.map(function(x) {
return (x.charCodeAt(0) + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65;
}); 

return String.fromCharCode.apply(this, strMap);
}


rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.");
```

Comment: Just rotate only the characters in the range that you want to rotate, and not others?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the current character is a space. If it is, return. Otherwise, shift the value:

```js
function rot13(str) {

  var strSplit = str.split('');
  var strMap = strSplit.map(function(x) {
    return x === ' '                           // Is it a space?
      ? x.charCodeAt(0)                        // Then return the space
      : (x.charCodeAt(0) + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65; // If not, then apply the shift.
  });

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(this, strMap);
}


console.log(rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK."));
```

Or, even better, only shift characters you want to:

```js
function rot13(str) {

  var strSplit = str.split('');
  var strMap = strSplit.map(function(x) {
    return /[a-zA-Z]/.test(x)                 // Is it a letter?
      ? (x.charCodeAt(0) + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65 // Shift it! 
      : x.charCodeAt(0)                       // Otherwise, return the not-letter.
  });

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(this, strMap);
}


console.log(rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK."));
```

Comment: Rather, instead of checking whether the character is one of those that we don't want to rotate, you should check whether it is one that you want to rotate. Spaces are not the only exception.

Comment: @Bergi: You're absolutely right. Fixed the answer :-)